# Format json string to work with json.loads()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have received a json format string from a API like below:

```py
string = ' {\n  "Ids": ["abc-765"],\n  "Type": "Column",\n  "Number": "021649015",\n  "Code": "02109998000",\n  "Text": , \n}'
```

Trying to get it work with json.loads but getting error:

```py
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 6 column 20 (char 162)
```

I think it's because of the missing value in the last key, and the additional tailing comma.

Is there a way I could format the string to get it working with json.loads?

Comment: Well, add it ;) But to be honest, your question is not worded very well, but I think I know what you mean. The question is, what other things does the api return? How reliably does it make that mistake?

Comment: The string is the only thing the API will returning, it's the content. Essentially we would expect keys have missing value, other than that the format won't be so different, plus the trailing comma.

Comment: Ok, to recap, the string always consists of one single dict, which always has a comma at the end, and may have missing values. Correct?

Comment: To be honest, if they specify it to be json, then they should change *their* code, and you shouldn't have to work around their mistake. That's my honest opinion. If you still have to, good luck, this one will become tedious

Comment: Except ... can you rely on them always having newlines in between?

Comment: Yes, there will always be new line in between.

Comment: You should really return a 400 error (assuming an HTTP API) to the API callee indicating the JSON decode issue. It's the callee that has the problem and should be resolving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible without making some assumptions. All of those assumptions need to be true for this algorithm to work:

- First line is always only `{`
- Last line is always only `}`
- All other lines contain exactly one key-value pair of the dictionary

```
import json


def fix_json(string):
    modifiedLines = []
    for line in string.splitlines()[1:-1]:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(','):
            line = line[:-1].strip()
        if line.endswith(':'):
            line = line + "null"
        modifiedLines.append(line)
    return '{\n' + ',\n'.join(modifiedLines) + '\n}'


string = ' {\n  "Ids": ["abc-765"],\n  "Type": "Column",\n  "Number": "021649015",\n  "Code": "02109998000",\n  "Text": , \n}'

modifiedString = fix_json(string)
jsonData = json.loads(modifiedString)
print(jsonData)
```

```
{'Ids': ['abc-765'], 'Type': 'Column', 'Number': '021649015', 'Code': '02109998000', 'Text': None}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly! I think the idea of handling the exceptions line by line is the right way to go. Although I was wondering if there is any modules/packages could handle that, but this looks great.

Comment: No there isn't, your case is too specific and far off from any norm. As I said, the real solution would be to fix the code that generated that broken json string.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys that you are expecting, you could add them to a list and iterate over this list, using regex to find the associated value:

```
for json_key in json_keys:
    val = None
    try:
        val = re.search(json_key+'": (.*),', string).group(1)
    catch AttributeError: # Key does not exist
        pass
    catch Exception as e:
        raise e from None
```

These values would need a little further validation/fixing (i.e. removing extra "" from the start and end) but you could add them to a key: value dictionary and pass this to

```
import json 
new_string = json.dumps(json_dict)
```